# SUMPRODUCT after SPLIT (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of products and quantities separated by / , which has this kind of structure:

```
products    qty's   
aaaa/bbbb   1/2
cccc/gggg   3/4
wwww/vvvv   6/5
```

I want to sum the qty's of all products , which manually looks like this:

```
aaaa    1
bbbb    2
cccc    3
gggg    4
wwww    6
vvvv    5
```

here is a link to my sheet     https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-oUY10Ij_FlWqh8DxXDo6THSKvjAT99rmK5unFqspo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IFERROR({FLATTEN(SPLIT(E3:E,"/")),FLATTEN(SPLIT(F3:F,"/"))}),"SELECT * WHERE Col1!='' OR Col2 IS NOT NULL"))`

-

[image]

Comment: is there a way to add a sumif based on this formula?

Comment: can you please look at the sheet i am sharing with you here and help me figure out why the formula is not working?               Here is the link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HjVOZKTL8mn2IO2-ujpnGbAwFfeXEPLMtDPMDdgJljM/edit#gid=0